# How to create dynamic route in Flask after form submit?

Tags: forms, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm not understanding how to create a dynamic route in Flask only after a user submits a form. The code below works, but I only want `/search/<query>` to be accessible after a form submit. With my current code, I can still access the page just by typing `/search/any-search-query` in my browser.

Here's what I am doing:

1 - This is the POST request for the form.

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s = request.form['search']
        return redirect(url_for('results', query=s))
    else:
        redirect(url_for('index'))
```

2 - When a user submits a form, redirect them to a new page with dynamic routing.

```
@app.route('/search/<query>', methods=['GET'])
def results(query):
    return render_template("results.html")
```

3 - This the form in my HTML file.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('submit') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use cookies or flask-session

Comment: @waynetech Can you please show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I am trying that works, but I don't know if this is a clean solution.

```
from flask import session
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    session['search'] = 'yes' # assign session value
    if request.form:
        s = request.form['search']
        return redirect(url_for('results', query=s))
    else:
        redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Then update

```
@app.route('/search/<query>', methods=['GET'])
def results(query):
    if session['search'] == 'yes':
        session['search'] = 'no' # assign new value to session
        return render_template("results.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: just use `session.get('search')` instead of `session['search']` or your app may crash when someone types the `/search?query=any-search-query` bypassing the form. Rest looks fine

Comment: @waynetech Ok thank you. Let me try this out.

Answer (score 0):

We can send a GET request to another page directly.

So in your template:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('results') }}" method="GET">
    <input type="search" id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in your `results` route:

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/search')
def results():
    query = request.args.get("query")
    # ...
    return render_template("results.html")
```

Note that if you want to get to the result page directly, you need to type `localhost:5000/search?query=any-search-query` instead of `/search/any-search-query`

Comment: I am trying to avoid letting users search by `localhost:5000/search?query=any-search-query`. How can I ensure that they only come to that page via the search form?